# JavaScript Basic Solution for Retrieving Files

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript, so please be patient with me. I've got a CSV file published to the web via Google, which is updated periodically. I have the URL of the file, and I want to write JS code which will retrieve that file when an HTML page is loaded, then convert it into a string so I can manipulate it and scoop out the values I want to place in different elements. The problem is, I have no idea how to request items from different URLs. I'm guessing there's some built-in functionality in JS to do what I want, but I'm completely in the dark on how to find it. Care to help me out?

Comment: You need [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: You may well run into cross-origin request issues with this - as it poses a security risk. If you have access to js code on the server, I would send my file open request from the browser to the server, and the server then fetches the file from the remote server. In any case you should make sure you sanitise the data you extract and place on your page to make sure you are not attacked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*published to the web via Google*"? You will need to publish it on your own domain, on the same where you are serving the HTML files that get filled by the JS.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `XMLHttpRequest`, but I'd recommend using jQuery's `$.ajax()` function as it decreases the complexity of sending asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery **$.ajax** or better [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to get the file contents.

Then you need to process it by using something like [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/).

PS. Papa Parse actually supports remote files directly so you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're looking for is [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    doSomethingWith(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://url/file.csv", true);
xhttp.send();
```

You could also use [jQuery's `ajax` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

```
$.ajax({url: "http://url/file.csv", success: function(result){
    doSomethingWith(result);
}});
```

This way, you get the result as a string which you can then use to retrieve the CSV values - look into the [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function for instance.

Be aware that you will not be able to try this locally without a webserver, since your browser will not allow your Javascript to fetch files from your computer. Indeed, your browser implements a mechanism called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) which restricts HTTP requests heading to a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish that .csv to google ? If so , can you program the file to be dumped to your web-content file?

I found I couldn't get files out of google drive with js, a lot of people had problems with this, then I tried to find a solution for it. So instead you can use platforms like github, or host on your server. Then the problem becomes way more straight forward.

I used python to grab the content I wanted , turn into .js file, or json file. Then use javascript to retrieve it.

```
    var data = http://mywebsite.com/my_file.json
```

or script src = http://my_website/data.js /script

Sorry about the above. Stackoverflow messing with my js. The above is just an example of the script tag 'my_website' needs to be programmes in.

Great place to start with json , and other resource here 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp